# smartparens how to stop behaviour of inserting backslash \ before I type a single quote '

Tags: text-editing, smartparens

I'm in C major mode, editing source files. Whenever I want to type a single quote `'` *smartparens* automatically gives me the following: `\'|\'` , where  `|` is the cursor position.

What I want exactly is this: `'|'`.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/issues/783) the author suggests setting `sp-escape-quotes-after-insert` to nil.

Comment: That did the job, thanks!